# Don't print lines where field#1 starts with contents of field#4

Tags: awk

Trying to exclude lines where field#1 starts with contents of field#4.  Otherwise print line.

INPUT

```
f1|f2|f3|f4
Cheese Board|xx|xxx|Cheese
French Cheese|yy|yyy|Cheese
```

OUTPUT NEEDED

```
f1|f2|f3|f4
French Cheese|yy|yyy|Cheese
```

CODE TRIED (not working with carat^)

```
awk ‘ BEGIN { FS=OFS="|" }
{ if ( $1 !~ ^$4  )  { print $0 } }
‘ file
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ awk -F'|' 'index($1,$4)!=1' file
f1|f2|f3|f4
French Cheese|yy|yyy|Cheese
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try following.

```
awk -F'[ |]' 'FNR==1{print;next} $1!=$NF'  Input_file
```